# How can i share data across multiple fragments in application?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-viewmodel

I am working on an application where i m taking input from users across multiple fragments under same activity, and then i am sending that data to firebase now how can i achieve that using shared viewmodel, if possible please guide me how can i achieve that, I am completely new to android.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to share data between fragments.
One way to do that is through ViewModels

Specifically, you'll need a view model like this:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

Then you have your fragments:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    fun select(item: Item) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

Notice that both fragments retrieve the activity that contains them. That way, when the fragments each get the ViewModelProvider, they receive the same SharedViewModel instance, which is scoped to this activity.

If you want to know more about this, refer to: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: hey brother thank you for help but the problem is i m writing code in JAVA, Can u help me in java

Comment: If you paste it inside your fragments/viewmodels it should translate it automatically in java

Comment: ok let me check brother

Comment: also brother what it means by  "both fragments retrieve the activity that contains them"??

Comment: It means that your fragments are attached on your activity. 
As you know, one activity can contain multiple fragments

Comment: I hope this answer your question

Comment: Yes i m trying to solve this problem from last many days read many articles, videos but not able to grasp the thing proprerly, hope this time it solves, lets see but thanks for your great help brother.

Comment: @VivekMFauzdar I updated my answer. The code is in java now. Let me know

Comment: yes brother it is fine now select method is in kotlin but i got it now no problem..thank you

Comment: May you accept my answer as valid please? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: done brother, also can i connect u on any social?